# Excel VBA - Selection.Hyperlinks(1).SubAddress Updating Multiple rows/ranges

Tags: excel, vba, hyperlink

The following VBA Subroutine copies/inserts a new row in a spreadsheet and then updates a hyperlink in the first cell of the new row (A2). Well, that is what I want it to do, but it is also updating the hyperlink of the row that was copied (A3). And I can't figure out why.

```
Sub New_Task()
Dim new_task_name As String
Dim new_ws As Worksheet

' Copy the new Tasks name
new_task_name = InputBox(Prompt:="New Task Name (no spaces)", Title:="New Task Name", Default:="new_task")
If new_task_name = "new_task" Or new_task_name = vbNullString Then
    Exit Sub
End If

' Copy the current second row for the new task.
Rows("2:2").Select
Selection.Copy
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown

' Set the task name in Cell A2
Range("A2").Select
ActiveCell.Value = new_task_name

' Insert a new sheet.
Sheets("Template").Copy After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
ActiveSheet.Name = new_task_name
Range("A2").Select
ActiveCell.Value = Date

' Now we have the new worksheet, update the hyperlink to it.
Worksheets("Main").Activate
Range("A2").Select
' FIXME: the following line updates the hyperlink in A2 and A3.
Selection.Hyperlinks(1).SubAddress = "'" & new_task_name & "'" & "!A1"

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Bond that worked, once I manually removed the 'other' link (Ctrl+K). Full answer, including the friendly name below. Although I still don't get why the original didn't work.

```
Sheets("Main").Range("A2") = "=HYPERLINK(""#'" & new_task_name & "'!A1"",""" & new_task_name & """ )"
```

Comment: If the answer was helpful, upvote or accept it to help others with a similar issue who may stumble upon this question. You can also accept your own answer, if you'd like. [SO Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a new hyperlink in your cell instead of updating the `SubAddress` of one that was copied:

```
' Old...
Worksheets("Main").Activate
Range("A2").Select
' FIXME: the following line updates the hyperlink in A2 and A3.
Selection.Hyperlinks(1).SubAddress = "'" & new_task_name & "'" & "!A1"

' New...
Sheets("Main").Range("A2") = "=HYPERLINK(""#'" & new_task_name & "'!A1"")"
```